# Responsive navigation is not showing in mobile and tablet

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i am creating a site which has a 4th level navigation but it seems like not appearing in mobile and tablet. Here is my code

```html
<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="services">Services</a></li>

<li>
  <a href="#">Products</a>       
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" >Food Products</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a >Baking & Cooking Aids</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="breadingmix" >Breading Mix</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a>Beverages</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="concentratedcocoa">Concentrated-Cocoa</a></li>
            <li><a href="concentratedpowder" >Concentrated Powder</a></li>
            <li><a href="energy-drink" >Energy Drink</a></li>
            <li><a href="carbonated-drink" >RTD - Carbonated Drink</a></li>
            <li><a href="juices" >RTD - Juices</a></li>
            <li><a href="milk-based" >RTD - Milk Based</a></li>
            <li><a href="beverages-tea">RTD - Tea</a></li>
            <li><a href="sports-drink" >Sports Drink</a></li>
            <li><a href="water" >Water</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Whenever I click on the `Beverages` menu the navigation is back to `Food Products`.

Can you help me with this one? Thank you!

Comment: Your html code appears to be incomplete. Missing closing tags.

Comment: How does it come back? All the `a` have unique `href`, Infact if i click on a link, it take me to `/hrefValue`. What exactly is the issue

Comment: It looks fine in desktop and laptop but when it comes to mobile and tablet whenever i click the beverages it goes back to Food Products category. To see the actual page here it my website http://www.mcdealmarketingcorporation.com/testpage please check the navigation if you click the beverages

Comment: This is an issue of your javascript. You have used some library that expands/collapses sections when clicked on mobile. Now since you already have one section expanded to reach the `Beverages` section, clicking on it collapses the section. 

No matter what section you click on after one expansion, it will surely collapse. Check your javascript and then tweak its behavior. It must only expand/collapse `sub-sections` of where you click. Right now it expands/collapses any open section.

Comment: Thank you i solve my problem by changing my jquery. Thanks!